# Unable to open or develop apps in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

I just downloaded the android studio for linux
The problem is after i start with a new project, I'm not able to see any activity files.
I have exactly followed the standard instructions for opening a new project.
[image: Here is a screenshot of the project]Also my sdk manager icon isn't highlighted. Please help

The culprit is probably the following error:

> Can't deserialize target data of key 'IdeaAndroidProject'. Given class loaders: [PluginClassLoader[org.jetbrains.android, 10.0]]: Can't deserialize target data of key 'IdeaAndroidProject'. Given class loaders: [PluginClassLoader[org.jetbrains.android, 10.0]]

**UPDATE**

I tried to install what and all libraries and also did some changes to build.gradle
Libraries I installed:

> zlib.i686 
>   libstdc++.i686
>   ncurses-libs.i686
>   libgcc.i686
>   glibc.i686

Code i added to build.gradle:

```
buildscript
{
    repositories
    {
         mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies
    {
          classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies
{
     compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
     compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
}

android
{
     compileSdkVersion 17
     buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"
     defaultConfig
     {
           minSdkVersion 4
           targetSdkVersion 16
     }
}
```

I finally ended up with one error:

> Gradle: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'App1Project'.
>   Gradle version 1.6 is required. Current version is 1.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally i successfully completed compilation.

I just went for an update from version 0.2.8 to 0.2.9 and emptied build.gradle.
It was probably a bug.